# XGBoost multivariate time series 3 periods prediction

Tags: time-series, python, boosting

I've read a lot about using xgboost to forecast time series, but I feel like I've completly lost my mind and can't understand something very basic.

Would like just a confirmation if my reasoning is correct.

I've got time series data to predict Sales (Y) monthly and to do so I want to use variables like:

- number of work days
- inflation
- Number of orders

So data looks like this:

[image]

I need to predict for September, 9 month. I don't have HICP, Orders etc. for September so I have to lag these features, right?

So I will be using HICP and number of orders from previous month and dataframe would look like this:

[image]

After I have df like this I train my model on all data without last row and I use last row as an input to prediction.

Let's say I get 7000 as prediction for September.

Now if I want to predict 2 periods forward, can I move my input variables 2 months back and use number of Orders from previous month to make prediction on October?

After I got prediction for September, I can append it to the data and use it as an input to the model, shift data variables (HICP and orders) once again so it will be -2, train it again with prediction from September and make prediction on next period?

My dataframe now looks like that and again last row will be an input to prediction.

[image]

Is that correct approach and I'm doing everything alright?
I know asking this might seem foolish, but I feel like everyone focus on evaluating the data with past variables and never really spend much time on preparing real forecasts.